# Silent authentication from workplace join machine in azure ad

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory

I am trying to achieve a silent or unattended authentication in Azure Ad. I am having a tablet on Windows 10 with workplace joined and user logged in. 
My tablet is joined with workplace "demo.onmicrosoft.com" & logged in user is amit@demo.onmicrosoft.com.

Till here all good. Now problem is in my app. i am having an app which is using the above mentioned AAD to get data from a webapi. WebApi/database are too hosted Azure but on some other subscription.**Kindly note there are two different Azure Subcriptions in the picture.**

If I allow interactive logon (using Azure Authentication popup window), its working absolutely fine. But if try to suppress that window, it returns a null authorization context.
Below is my code.

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Authenticate a user against azure ad
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>true if authenticated otherwise false</returns>
        public bool Authenticate()
        {
            var success = false;
            AuthenticationResult result = null;
            // first, try to get a token silently
            try
            {
                result = _authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(ResourceId, ClientId).Result;
            }
            catch (AggregateException exc)
            {
                AdalException ex = exc.InnerException as AdalException;
                // There is no token in the cache; prompt the user to sign-in.
                if (ex != null && ex.ErrorCode != "failed_to_acquire_token_silently")
                {
                    // An unexpected error occurred.
                    success = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    //var uc = new UserPasswordCredential("amit@demo.onmicrosoft.com","*********");
                    // if you want to use Windows integrated auth.
                    var uc = new UserCredential();
                    try
                    {
                        result = _authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(ResourceId, ClientId,uc).Result;
                    }
                    catch 
                    {
                        //some unexpected error, set auth failed
                        success = false;
                    }

                }
            }
            if (result != null)
            {
                AccessToken = result.AccessToken;
                success = AccessToken.Length > 0;
            }
            return success;
        }
```

Comment: Were you developing a UWP project which consume the web API which register on other tenant? How did you init the instance of `_authContext` and what's the detail exception you have got when you using resource owner password credential flow to get the access token?

Comment: @FeiXue-MSFT . here's my scenario. App is not an UWP app. Its normal win form app (using .net 4.6.1). There are two domains in use 1. demo.onmicrosoft.com & 2. abc.onmicrosoft.com #1 is having my azure ad (with users /apps) #2.  is where my api is hosted. I registered my api (webapp/webapi) with demo.microsoft.com Azure AD. My laptop/tablets are workplace joined with demo.onmicrosoft.com and logged in with user amit.

Comment: Did you mean that you want to acquire the token via the login account for the device instead of using the **resource owner password credential flow**?

Comment: @FeiXue-MSFT Yes. Indeed. I dont want to display that azure authentication popup. Since my device is already workplace joined, so you can say i dont want to provide user id and pass again.